# eslint return a false positive for "no-unused-vars"

Tags: vuejs3, eslint, vite

I'm using Vite + Vue3

I installed:

- eslint (8.33.0)
- eslint-plugin-vue (9.9.0)
- vite-plugin-eslint (1.8.1)

In `vite.config.js` I have:

```
[...]
import eslint from 'vite-plugin-eslint'

export default ({ mode }) => {
  return defineConfig({
    […some conf…],
    plugins: [
     basicSsl(), // to have a local `https` server
     vue(),
     vuetify(),
     { // do not fail on serve (i.e. local development)
       ...eslint({
         failOnWarning: false,
         failOnError: false,
         lintOnStart:true,
         include:['src/**/*.js', 'src/**/*.vue']
       }),
       apply: 'serve',
       enforce: 'post'
     }
   ]
 })
}
```

In `.eslintrc.cjs` I have:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2022: true
  },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:vue/vue3-recommended'
  ],
  globals: {
    "process":false
  },
  rules: {
    'no-console': [
      "warn",
      { "allow": ["clear", "info", "error", "dir", "trace", "log"] }
    ],
    'no-extra-semi': 'off',
    'no-useless-escape': 'off',
    'vue/multi-word-component-names': 'off',
    'vue/html-self-closing': 'off',
    'vue/max-attributes-per-line': 'off',
    'vue/order-in-components': 'off',
    'vue/component-definition-name-casing': 'off'
  }
}
```

In my `.vue` files I have the below loops:

```
for (let [value, id] of existingLabels) {
   values.push({id:id, value:value});
}
[…]
for (let monthName in this.valuesGrouped[year]) {
  if (!this.checked.includes(year+'-'+monthName)) {
    this.checked.push(year+'-'+monthName);
  }
}
```

And `eslint` returns errors:

```
210:19  error  'value' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
210:26  error  'id' is defined but never used     no-unused-vars

140:36  error  'monthName' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
```

I don't use TypeScript or Babel. I use modules that will be loaded in modern browsers.

Any idea why I got these error messages from ESlint??

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: it's because I included a folder that wasn't in my current project folder. My `vite.config.js` was actually like that:

```
[...]
import eslint from 'vite-plugin-eslint'

export default ({ mode }) => {
  return defineConfig({
    […some conf…],
    plugins: [
     basicSsl(), // to have a local `https` server
     vue(),
     vuetify(),
     { // do not fail on serve (i.e. local development)
       ...eslint({
         failOnWarning: false,
         failOnError: false,
         lintOnStart:true,
         include:['src/**/*.js', 'src/**/*.vue', '/other/folder/project/src/*.vue']
       }),
       apply: 'serve',
       enforce: 'post'
     }
   ]
 })
}
```

And I had an old `.eslintrc` file in that `/other/folder/project/`, which was causing this false-positive.

So I deleted `/other/folder/project/.eslintrc`.

However it created a new error: `No ESLint configuration found in /other/folder/project/`.
To fix it, I changed my `vite.config.js` using the option `overrideConfigFile` ([see the doc](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/integrate/nodejs-api#-new-eslintoptions)):

```
[...]
import eslint from 'vite-plugin-eslint'

export default ({ mode }) => {
  return defineConfig({
    […some conf…],
    plugins: [
     basicSsl(), // to have a local `https` server
     vue(),
     vuetify(),
     { // do not fail on serve (i.e. local development)
       ...eslint({
         failOnWarning: false,
         failOnError: false,
         lintOnStart:true,
         overrideConfigFile:'.eslintrc.cjs',
         include:['src/**/*.js', 'src/**/*.vue', '/other/folder/project/src/*.vue']
       }),
       apply: 'serve',
       enforce: 'post'
     }
   ]
 })
}
```